# ESRI Geometry API - how to choose QuadTree query tolerance

Tags: java, gis

I'm playing around with the [ESRI Geometry API](https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java).  The documentation for the [`getIterator` methods](http://esri.github.io/geometry-api-java/javadoc/com/esri/core/geometry/QuadTree.html#getIterator(com.esri.core.geometry.Envelope2D,%20double)) doesn't explain what the `tolerance` parameter does.  The code doesn't shed much light on what kind of values would be appropriate.  The unit tests all use `0.0`, except for a single test that uses `0.001`.

What factors should I consider when choosing a value for `tolerance`?  To put it another way, if the best value is typically `0.0`, when would it be something else?

Comment: *"The tolerance ensures that the iterator visits quads and features that are in the tolerance reach from the query envelope / segment."* - [How to use QuadTree Issue #65](https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java/issues/65#issuecomment-60507592)

Comment: @JonnyHenly That doesn't tell me anything about how to choose a good value.

Answer (score 0):

[Generally 1mm](https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java/wiki#tolerance).  So for example if the coordinates are WGS84, you can use 1e-8 degrees.